# ggplot fill with a variable and spatially separate

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using the given script I created the following plot.
[image]

However I would like to achieve sth different - as presented at the hand-drawn graph.
 [image]

1. fill with the colour based on the time point
2. spatially separate type2 (one, two)

Thank you for help.

```
ggplot(df.summary, aes(x=type, y=len))+ 
  geom_errorbar(
    aes(ymin = len-sem, ymax = len+sem, fill=name),
    position = position_dodge(0.8), width = 0.4)+
  geom_bar(aes(type, len, fill = name), stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.8), width = 0.5)+
  geom_jitter(data=df2, aes(x=type, y=len, fill=name), 
              trim = FALSE, binaxis='y', stackdir='center', 
              size = 0.5, position = position_dodge(0.8), color = "black", alpha=0.7)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("black", 
                               "black",

                               "grey",
                               "grey",

                               "red", 
                               "red",

                               "green",
                               "green"))+
  theme_classic()+
  labs(x="Type", y = " Level")
```

```
df.summary
 name type        sd       len n        sem time type2
a    m        NA 6.2621873 1         NA   1h   one
b    m 0.2077490 0.4990392 3 0.11994393   1h   two
c    m 0.1680071 0.7187899 3 0.09699895   2h   one
d    m 2.0459271 2.4915555 3 1.18121658   2h   two
e    m 0.1587378 0.6325991 3 0.09164730   3h   one
f    m 1.4944003 1.9640103 3 0.86279240   3h   two
g    m 4.1507568 3.3866492 3 2.39644054   4h   one
h    m 1.6552674 1.5458941 2 1.17045083   4h   two
```

```
df2
name type       len time type2
a    m 6.2621873   1h   one
b    m 0.3081419   1h   two
b    m 0.7202984   1h   two
b    m 0.4686772   1h   two
c    m 0.7640117   2h   one
c    m 0.5328003   2h   one
c    m 0.8595579   2h   one
d    m 3.0244371   2h   two
d    m 0.2319148   2h   two
d    m 4.2183145   2h   two
e    m 0.4495853   3h   one
e    m 0.7153230   3h   one
e    m 0.7328890   3h   one
f    m 2.8316965   3h   two
f    m 2.8218996   3h   two
g    m 1.1108520   4h   one
g    m 8.1775386   4h   one
g    m 0.8715568   4h   one
h    m 0.3754432   4h   two
h    m 2.7163449   4h   two
```

Comment: I think you might be looking for `+ facet_grid(~ type2)`

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved with a single call to `geom_bar`.

Assuming you want `len` as the height the simplest example would be:

```
ggplot(data = df.summary) + 
    geom_bar(aes(type2, len, fill = time), stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

[image: barplot illustration of code output]